# bounded Generic Comparator for base and derived classes

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand how to build a generic Comparator for the a given class and all derived class.

```
public class Employee {
    String  name;
    int id;
}
```

In my main class, I tried this

```
Comparator<T extends Employee> comp = new Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName);
```

and the IDE gives me the error

```
Unexpected bound
```

Comment: Why did you write `Comparator<T extends Employee>`? Did you mean `Comparator<? super Employee>`?

Comment: How do you get the error `Unexpected bound`? The problem seems to not be about the comparator.

Comment: @Sweeper , yes I think that was the problem, got the problem once I posted the question.

Comment: Additionally, you don't want the `new` before `Comparator.comparing`: it's a method, not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Comparator<? extends Employee> comp = Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Maurice Perry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752307/3788176) might be right in terms of allowing that line to compile, but it's not very useful afterwards: you can't invoke `comp.compare` with any other arguments than literal `null`s.

`Comparator<? extends Employee>` means that the comparator accepts a *specific, but unknown* subclass of `Employee`: since the compiler does not know which subclass it is, it will only allow you to pass in something that it knows for sure can be safely cast to that unknown type: namely, `null`.

If you want a comparator which is somehow more generic than a `Comparator<Employee>`, you could use `Comparator<? super Employee>`, which means the comparator can safely accept an instance of `Employee` (but the concrete object may be able to safely accept a more general thing).

---

But really, you don't want to use any sort of wildcard here. Wildcards are only really useful in method parameters, in order to make a method able to accept more general objects.

You shouldn't use them in variables or return types (etc) because you're stuck with the wildcard type once you've got it - you can't (safely) cast away the wildcards, so you are stuck with the extra verbosity of the `? extends` or `? super` everywhere, which is really just unnecessary eye pain.

---

The reason why `Comparator<T extends Employee>` doesn't work is that is attempting to declare a type variable, `T`: you can only do that on a class (or interface) or on a method signature. It doesn't make sense to be able to declare it inside a method, since you can't subsequently use that type `T`.